# Unable to override "From" in SharePoint SendEmail Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the below code but I still get the outgoing "From email" which is mentioned outgoing email settings in CA.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function processSendEmails() {

    var from = 'abc@testing.com',
        to = 'xyz@testing',
        body = 'Hello World Body',
        subject = 'Hello World Subject';

    // Call sendEmail function
    //
    sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}


function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
    //Get the relative url of the site
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': 'globalPSIAppProducts@deloitte.com',
                'To': {
                    'results': [to]
                },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}

/* $(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});
*/
</script> 

}

{
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>

<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="processSendEmails()" />

</form>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with the code snippet below and it works for a normal user email address for From:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function processSendEmails() {

    var from = 'contoso\\user1',
        to = 'contoso\\administrator',
        body = 'Hello World Body',
        subject = 'Hello World Subject';

    // Call sendEmail function
    //
    sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}


function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
    //Get the relative url of the site
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': from,
                'To': {'results': [to]},
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});

</script>
```

Result of the mail User1 send to Administrator for example:
[image]

For my side, it has override the From address in the Email OutGoing settings:
[image]

I saw in your code snippet, From email address has a hard code address, please check if this address is the same as the address in CA OutGoing Email settings.